# Blazor Dropdown onchange only triggering via keyboard, not mouse

Tags: blazor, dropdown, onchange

i have a *really* weird problem. I am using blazor .net 8, and have a simple dropdown and an onchange event.

```
    <select @onchange="SelectedChanged">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

@code {

```
public void SelectedChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
}
```

}

The SelectedChanged event **ONLY** triggers if i change the dropdown using the keyboard keys (focus on it, then up/down arrows).

If i use a mouse to click on it, and click one of the options, it *doesn't* trigger.

Ultimately, this should work, right? If i change the dropdown into a 'multiple' one:

```
   <select @onchange="SelectedChanged" multiple>
```

then, via the mouse, the onchange works no problem. Other controls like buttons etc also trigger onchange when clicked with a mouse.

Comment: Which render mode are you using with .Net 8 RC2 ?

Comment: I have tried vairious, including using @rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly. 

But, because it works if i use 'multiple' or keyboard to go up and down the options, and other elements (buttons, input text, textarea etc) doesn't really correlate.It really seems like .netcore8 bug? How would i report it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I've tested it to make sure: here's a repo - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO77439384